# Hasn't been approved for display in App Center Facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a implement Facebook invite API, when I used my Facebook account login to send the invite to Facebook account test. After that I go to web browser to login with account test, I can saw the invite message(which I had send before) on the Activity. But when I click Accept button on Facebook, I receipt the message:

> Sorry, FirstApp hasn't been approved for display in App Center.

(The FirstApp is my app name for Facebook API). How can I click Accept then my app can receive this action from users which had invited from my app?